# Prestashop hookDisplayAdminOrder cannot receive variable

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to get an order reference using my module,

Here is my module function

```
public function hookDisplayAdminOrder($params) {
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array('order' => $params['objOrder']));
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'smartB.tpl');
}
```

And here is how am i trying to get a variable

```
<div class="panel">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <i class="icon-truck"></i>
    {l s='Something'}
</div>
<div class="tab-content panel">
    <h4 class="visible-print">{l s='Something'}</h4>
    {$order|@var_dump}          
</div>
```

The output is NULL, should print an array.
Sorry for a stupid question or bad English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's NULL because there is no `objOrder` in `$params` only `id_order`.

[Hook execution in admin order template](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/admin-dev/themes/default/template/controllers/orders/helpers/view/view.tpl#L881)

This is the correct way of getting order data to your template.

```
public function hookDisplayAdminOrder($params) {
    $order = new Order((int)$params['id_order']);
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array('order' => $order));

    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'smartB.tpl');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help!